# How To Add Timestamp On The Android Notification?

Tags: android, push-notification

I'm trying to add to the android push notification the timestamp when it was created. What is the best manner to implement that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the `Notification.Builder` [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setWhen(long)) you can simply use the following:

```
setWhen(long when)
setShowWhen(boolean show);
```

When you set a timestamp with the `setWhen(long when)` method, `setShowWhen` is `true` by default, so calling `setShowWhen(true)` is optionally.

Comment: Update: For apps targeting N and above, this defaults to false. For earlier apps, the default is true.

Answer (score 0):

From API Level 17 onwards, you can use setShowWhen(true)

> public Notification.Builder setShowWhen (boolean show)
>
> Added in API level 17 Control whether the timestamp set with setWhen
>   is shown in the content view.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setShowWhen(boolean)